# Gradle could not update last-bin.build >Access is denied

Tags: windows, gradle

Whenever I try to run a gradle task, it fails with the following error.

```
Could not update C:\...\.gradle\8.0\fileChanges\last-build.bin
> Access is denied
```

I tried checking if the file was hidden at the given location. But it was not. I even tried setting the files permission to not include read only.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows. And you've tried other solutions like unhiding the file. There's a good chance Windows Defender is blocking an "unknown" program from accessing your file.

Type in "Virus and threat protection" in the search bar. And then click on protection history. If you see "Protected folder access blocked", confirm whether it's the gradle folder by clicking on it. And then select "Allow on device" from the Actions drop down.

If you want to remove protected folders completely. This can be done by navigating to "Ransomware Protection" in the settings app, and turning it off from there. It's not recommended though. Make sure you turn it back on once your done.